# Understanding Try-Catch and Exception Handling in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm beginning to work with Try-Catches in Java.  I'm getting an error in my catch that says "Unhandled exception type InvalidBalanceException".

This is my Person object:

```
public Person(String name, int age, double bankAccountBalance) {
    boolean trueOrFalse = false;
    setName(name);
    setAge(age);
    while(trueOrFalse == false) {
        try {
             setAccountBalance(bankAccountBalance);
        } catch(InvalidBalanceException e) {
            throw new InvalidBalanceException(e+": You did not enter a double");
          }
    }
}
```

This is my InvalidBalanceException:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InvalidBalanceException extends Exception{

    public InvalidBalanceException() {}

    public InvalidBalanceException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me some insight into what I need to do with this?

Comment: If you catch an exception and rethrow it, what was the point of catching it in the first place?

Comment: You need to add exception handling where you instantiate the Person object. If you need more clarification, then also show the code where this Person object is getting created

Answer (score 1):

An exception is something unexpected to occur that you must handle, in this case you want this exception to be thrown when someone creates an instance of the Person and does not enter a double, if you actually want to test if the user inputs something else than a number or an invalid number (a ver big number or something like that) then your constructor should receive a Number instead, or a String and you should try to parse or convert that value to double, if you cant, then throw the exception.

But if you instance an object just like your class needs and put anything different than a double, the compiler won't let you get to that point either way.